# Why is my AccBal integer getting set back to '0' value

Tags: java, eclipse, object, constructor

The following is my code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Bank_Account {

    private String FName, LName;
    private int Pin;
    private long Min, Max, CardNum;
    private double Interest, AccBal;

    public Bank_Account() {
        this.Interest = 0.06;
    }


    public Bank_Account(String FName, String LName) {
        this.FName = FName;
        this.LName = LName;
        this.Max = 1000000000000000L;
        this.Min = 9999999999999999L;
        this.CardNum = Min + (long) (Math.random() * (Max - Min));
    }

    public Bank_Account(int Pin1) {
        this.Pin = Pin1;
        if (Pin < 10000 && Pin > 999) {
            System.out.println("Pin Accepted!");
        }
        else {
            System.out.println("Invalid Input! Exiting System . . .");
            System.exit(0);
        }
    }

    public void print() {
        System.out.println("First Name: " + FName);
        System.out.println("Last Name: " + LName);
        System.out.println("This is your Card Number: " + CardNum);
    }

    public void printPin() {
        System.out.println("Pin: " + Pin + "\nPlease remember it!");
    }

    public void printBal() {
        System.out.println("This is your Account Balance Right Now: " + this.AccBal);
    }

    public double Dep(double DepIn) {
        this.Accbal = this.AccBal + DepIn;
        return AccBal;
    }

    public double Wit(double WitIn) {

        return AccBal - WitIn;
    }

    public void Inter() {
        this.AccBal = this.AccBal * (this.Interest + 1.00);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int count = 0;
        int year = 2019;
        String word;

        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

        Bank_Account Bal = new Bank_Account();

        System.out.println("Please input Name");
        Bank_Account Info = new Bank_Account(input.nextLine(), input.nextLine());

        System.out.println("Please input Pin");
        Bank_Account Pin = new Bank_Account(input.nextInt());


        Info.print();
        Pin.printPin();

        while (true) {

            if (count >= 12) {
                count = 1;
                year = year + 1;
                System.out.println("Its " + year + " Congratulations!");
                Bal.Inter();
            }

            count++;

            word = input.nextLine();
            System.out.println("What would you like to do");
            word = input.nextLine();

            // this is where i input the value
            if (word.equalsIgnoreCase("Deposit")) {
                Bal.Dep(input.nextDouble());
            }

            // and this is where the balance is checked
            if (word.equalsIgnoreCase("Balance")) {
                Bal.printBal();
            }

            if (word.equalsIgnoreCase("Withdraw")) {

            }

            if (word.equalsIgnoreCase("Exit")) {
                System.out.println("Exiting System . . . .");
                break;
            }

        }

        input.close();
    }

}
```

When i try to check the Account Balance after depositing some value, the value of AccBal returns to 0.

I am entering the value in main and all the calculation stuff is happening with the objects and constructors.

There could be some silly mistakes here and there, please ignore those and focus on the AccBal varibale and others related to that.

I feel like there is a problem with constructors but i just cant figure it out, I am also a new java programmer still learning more.
Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: You are instantiating three Objects of type `Bank_Account` - why?

Comment: To have different constructors for different objects. So I don't have to put everything in one constructor

Answer (score -1):

I run your program and it is working. It was able to return the balance after Deposit. Can you describe your full test setp

Comment: What IDE did you run it in

Comment: What I am doing is imputing my first name then last name. Then I would do the pin. Then I am typing deposit, then I would type in balance afterwords.

Comment: Hi, I am using eclipse Version: 2018-12 (4.10.0) and java 8. I did the exact same step as you and it is working. have you tried running it on debug mode to see what happens in each step?